# How to use `_.partial` with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, underscore.js

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';

const partialFn = _.partial(fn, _, fixedArg);
```

elicits a type error. I've tried type casting the `_` argument with `<any>` but that doesn't fix the issue.

How is `_.partial` supposed to be used with TypeScript?

Comment: Have you installed `@types/underscore`?

Comment: Doing so didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: "elicits a type error" --- what error?

Comment: ```
Type error: Argument of type '{ default: UnderscoreStatic; each<T>(list: List<T>, iterator: ListIterator<T, void>, context?: any): List<T>; each<T>(object: Dictionary<T>, iterator: ObjectIterator<T, void>, context?: any): Dictionary<...>; ... 133 more ...; chain<T>(obj: T[]): _Chain<...>; chain<T>(obj: Dictionary<...>): _Chain<...>; chain<T exte...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UnderscoreStatic'.
```

Comment: What if you `import _ from 'underscore';` instead? It looks like `UnderscoreStatic` is the default export.

Comment: That did the trick. Convert your comment into an answer and I'll upvote it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `UnderscoreStatic` is defined as a `default` export one should

```
import _ from 'underscore';
```

instead.

It would satisfy the type checker and the rest of the code should not change (since underscore exports both as named exports and as a properties of a default export).